# preg_replace not working in for loop

Tags: php, regex, for-loop

I want to include files using shortcode, but problem is that preg_replace isn't working properly in for loop.my code is below:

```
    <?php
$output = "[@include('file1')] [@include('file2')]";
if(preg_match_all("/\[\@include\(\'(.*?)\'\)\]/", $output, $match)){
    for($i=0;$i<count($match);$i++){
        $output = preg_replace("/\[\@include\(\'(.*?)\'\)\]/", $match[1][$i], $output);
    }
}
echo $output;
```

the above code prints "file1 file1", it should be print "file1 file2" both file name but it is not printing the both files name.Please tell where i'm wrong.

Comment: Do you want to just get the `'file1 file2'`?

Comment: yes, but file1 file2 may be changed.

Comment: You are escaping extra things. You could just have `/\[@include\('(.*?)'\)\]/`. The `@` isn't special, nor is the `'`. If you were using single quotes around your pattern you would need to escape the single quotes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is already in the output array of your regular expression (i.e. in the `$match` array), you just need to get it using `implode()`!

```
<?php
$output = "[@include('file1')] [@include('file2')]";
preg_match_all("/\[\@include\(\'(.*?)\'\)\]/", $output, $match);
echo $out = implode(' ', $match[1]);
?>
```